# CSS alignment issue with a div and an image

Tags: html, css

I don't even know if this is possible. If you check out the image below, you'll see a purple box and a white box. The white box has a photo of my dog Zuko. I'm trying to keep the right edge of that photo perfectly aligned with the right edge of the purple box behind it. But of course, when you start changing the screen size slightly it is no longer aligned. Is there any way to fix those two divs together so when the screen is adjusted, they adjust together and stay aligned? 
I tried fixing them both to absolute, using percentages, but I don't even know if what I'm aiming for is possible.

box1 is the purple box, box2 the white containing the photo.

[image: page image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZUKO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="zuko-title" src="zuko-title.svg" alt="Zuko">
    <div id="box1" class="floater"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="floater">
      <div class="intro-text">
        <h3>hi, i'm Zuko the dog.</h3>
      </div>
      <img id="zuko-bolts" src="zuko-bolts.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="floater">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">frolicking</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">my 'rents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

.floater {
  position: absolute;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: #DB7ACC;
  width: 74%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 17%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 84%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 11%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#zuko-bolts {
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7.2%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Some `html` would be very helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: HTML would definitely be helpful. CSS is only half the thing.

Comment: doh! sorry, just added. @Jhecht

Comment: `#box1` and `#box2` are the amin subjects, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne yes box1 is the purple box and box2 is the white box containing the photo.

Comment: Can you host your images somewhere and put them in your code so that they work?

Comment: [Got part way through](https://jsfiddle.net/L6rzmobq/).. i would suggest reordering the html, and styling so that boxes are contained within each other so they "move" relative to the position of their ancestors

Answer (score 3):

1. Place `#box2` within `box#1`.
2. Since they are both positioned and the child (i.e. `#box2`) is `absolute`, we would be able to position `#box2` within the confines of `#box1`.
3. If we want the right edge of `#box2` to be flush with the right edge of `#box1`, set `#box2` `right:0;` this will work for any edge so `top:0;` would set the top edge of `#box2` to the top edge of `#box1`, and so on.
4. If we review the Snippet in Full page mode we'll see that no matter how the viewport (width of screen) changes, `#box2` will not only conform in size relative to `#box1`, it will consistently stay in the same position relative to `#box1`'s borders.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.floater {
  position: absolute;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #DB7ACC;
  width: 74%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 17%;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 84%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 25%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background: url(http://news.vet.tufts.edu/wp-content/uploads/national-pet-dental-health-month.jpg)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px dashed #db7acc;
}
#zuko-bolts {
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7.2%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ZUKO</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="zuko-title" src="zuko-title.svg" alt="Zuko">

  <div id="box1" class="floater">

    <div id="box2" class="floater"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="intro-text">
    <h3>hi, i'm Zuko the dog.</h3>
  </div>
  <img id="zuko-bolts" src="zuko-bolts.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class="floater">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">frolicking</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">my 'rents</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">stuff</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on in this question... Here's how I might approach the layout you've asked for. Let me know if you have specific questions.

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/qRPQay)

For the purple box...
Wrap the image in a container and then use a pseudoelement to create the border.

**Example**

```
.image-container {
  height: 150%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 90%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid purple;
}
```

**Full snippet**

```css
body {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 150px auto 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}
.intro-text {
  position: relative;
}
.intro-text h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 120px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  top: -240px;
  left: 120px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 84%;
  z-index: 3;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
#box2::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.image-container {
  height: 150%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}
.image-container::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 90%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid purple;
}
#zuko-bolts {
  width: 40%;
}
#box3 {
  /* this menu is strangely coded */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -150px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<img id="zuko-title" src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Zuko">
<div id="box1" class="floater"></div>
<div id="box2" class="floater">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h3>ZUKO</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="zuko-bolts" src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="box3" class="floater">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">frolicking</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">my 'rents</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">stuff</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so the problem is, if you look at the zuko photo with the lightening botls in the background, both of those are one image. so the edge of the lightening bolts lines up perfectly. But when I use margin-right or whatever to move it over so the photo itself is lined up, that's where they don't stay aligned together.

Comment: Give the image position: absolute, then apply a negative right position until the bolts go where you want, and the dog lines up. http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/bgoQxB

Comment: yesss thank you. i realize from your code what the problem was. so stupid. i had zuko-bolts set to height, not width. that was the one tiny thing that kept messing up the alignment. thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2):

I had a different method than Ed, and it could be that it isn't exactly what you need but if you can explain your what you need I'd be more than happy to help you.

I was having a hard time with your HTML, so I changed it a little bit. Hopefully you can figure out on your own which parts you need to change or add.

I tried to comment the code as completely as I could in case you were having trouble understanding.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  /*Makes the height and margin for both the HTML and Body elements 100% of the available height, also removes margins.*/
}
.wrapper.zuko {
  /*The wrapper for the stuff so that we don't polute our regular HTML with styles and colors we don't need.*/
  position: relative;
  /* Makes absolute positioning work as expected for child elements*/
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  /*Make it 100% as tall as its parent*/
  width: 80%;
  /* but only 80% as wide*/
  margin: 50px auto;
  /* 50px margin on the top and bottom, automatic padding on the left and right*/
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper.zuko .zuko-title {
  position: absolute;
  /*Changes how this is positioned with respect to its parent.*/
  height: 25px;
  /*makes the element 25 pixels high*/
  line-height: 50px;
  /*Probably not needed, but it was ther*/
  font-size: 45px;
  /*How big is the title text? Hella.*/
  padding-left: 5px;
  /* Little bit of padding on the left to ensure it's not right on the border */
  top: -25px;
  /* positioned 25 pixels above the top border of it's parent */
  left: 5%;
  /* left by 5%*/
  right: 10%;
  /* right by 10% */
  background-color: #cd00cd;
  /*random purple color */
}
.wrapper.zuko .zuko-title .zuko-title-img {
  position: absolute;
  /*again, changes how this thing is positioned by its parent*/
  right: 0;
  /* directly on the right edge */
  top: 100%;
  /* 100% of the elements height from the top edge of the element */
}
.wrapper.zuko .zuko-title .zuko-title-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  /*Twitches the text above the purple border like in image.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper zuko">
  <div class="zuko-title">
    <div class="zuko-title-text">
      Zuko
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200?text=Zuko" alt="" class="zuko-title-img" />
  </div>
  <div>Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#zuko-bolts {
position: absolute;
height: 50%;
right: 7.14%;
top: 0;
}
```

Purple box's right side is 6% more to the right of the white box's right side. Since the image is located inside the white box, you need to find the equal of that 6% screen size distance in a 84% box. So basically, 6x100/84=7.14 approximately.

Comment: sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding...how did you get 6%? Would you be able to explain a little better?

Comment: purple box 15% on the left + 74% width makes 89% so it's 11% from the right side. 
white box 11% on the left +84% width makes 95% so it's 5% from the right side. 
So the difference between the right side of the purple box and right side of the white box is 6%

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks so much everyone for helping. All I had to do was change height: 50% to width and that made it align like it was supposed to.